# Ruby on Rails web service for user login for mobile app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building both web & mobile app in which I am using ROR for building web application. I am using Rails 4 and Devise 3 for the authentication module and implemented it in my application. But now I want to build web services for user authentication from mobile app. I have followed these tutorials [First one](http://matteomelani.wordpress.com/2011/10/17/authentication-for-mobile-devices/)  and [Second one](http://lucatironi.github.io/tutorial/2012/10/15/ruby_rails_android_app_authentication_devise_tutorial_part_one/) but when I test these services it says 500 : Internal server error, here is pic. [image]

Apart of this, I think token_authenticable has been degraded...so kindly let me know where I went wrong or provide me some good tutorials to create web services in ROR with devise authentication. Thanks

> ```
> activesupport (4.0.2)
> lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:424:in `load' activesupport
> (4.0.2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:424:in `block in
> load_file' activesupport (4.0.2)
> lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:616:in `new_constants_in'
> activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:423:in
> `load_file' activesupport (4.0.2)
> lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require_or_load'
> activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:463:in
> `load_missing_constant' activesupport (4.0.2)
> lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
> activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in
> `const_get' activesupport (4.0.2)
> lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `block in
> constantize' activesupport (4.0.2)
> lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `each'
> activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in
> `inject' activesupport (4.0.2)
> lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `constantize'
> activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:535:in
> `get' activesupport (4.0.2)
> lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:566:in `constantize' actionpack
> (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in
> `controller_reference' actionpack (4.0.2)
> lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `controller'
> actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:44:in
> `call' actionpack (4.0.2)
> lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
> actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in
> `each' actionpack (4.0.2)
> lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call' actionpack
> (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
> warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call' warden
> (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch' warden (1.2.3)
> lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call' rack (1.5.2)
> lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call' rack (1.5.2)
> lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call' rack (1.5.2)
> lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call' actionpack (4.0.2)
> lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
> actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in
> `call' rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in
> `context' rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in
> `call' actionpack (4.0.2)
> lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
> activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
> activerecord (4.0.2)
> lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in
> `call' activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in
> `call' actionpack (4.0.2)
> lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
> activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in
> `_run__3149087440152064127__call__callbacks' activesupport (4.0.2)
> lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks' actionpack
> (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
> actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in
> `call' actionpack (4.0.2)
> lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
> actionpack (4.0.2)
> lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
> actionpack (4.0.2)
> lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
> railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
> railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
> activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in
> `block in tagged' activesupport (4.0.2)
> lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged' activesupport
> (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
> railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call' actionpack
> (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
> rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call' rack (1.5.2)
> lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call' activesupport (4.0.2)
> lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call' rack
> (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call' actionpack (4.0.2)
> lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call' rack (1.5.2)
> lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call' railties (4.0.2)
> lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call' railties (4.0.2)
> lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call' rack (1.5.2)
> lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call' rack (1.5.2)
> lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call' rack (1.5.2)
> lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
> /usr/share/ruby/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
> /usr/share/ruby/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
> /usr/share/ruby/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in
> start_thread'
> ```

Comment: What is the exception (and stacktrace) ?

Comment: it is not giving any exception ...I checked it in server console..

Comment: Scroll down the 500 error 'data' in rest client - that is returning html with exception information; note the html title 'action controller: exception caught'

Comment: thanks, updated the question with exception...

Comment: That is only the stacktrace, what is the exception? Based on stacktrace might be a routing syntax error? Maybe caused by v1 in path?

Comment: aha....i think this is the one you want ask...it is some syntax error let me check..."sessions_controller.rb:29: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end):"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43889/discussion-between-jeet-and-house9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and it was my bad that I missed something very silly or I am nood to ruby on rails.

Whenever you face 500 Internal error, please do check following things

1. Check your logs on rails server side, it is very useful
2. This problem is mainly due to Syntax problem in your rails side code
3. It may be the problem with the parameter you are passing or actual fields exits your model
4. Check for the validation in your model, it may blocks your request

I think mostly the problem lies in these issues but may be I am missing few.